# How do i get rid of methods for view in model class

Tags: php, yii

In models i always create some methods that used only in views like this:

```
<?php $this->widget('CGridView', [
'id' => 'sales-list',
'columns' => [
    [
        'header' => 'id',
        'name' => 'id',
        'type' => 'raw',
        'value' => '$data->getViewId()'
    ],
    [
        'header' => 'Int ID',
        'name' => 'Int_id',
        'value' => '$data->getInternalId()',
    ],
```

In model i have code

```
public function getInternalId()
{
    ...
}

public function getViewId()
{
    ...
}
```

By creating this methods my model rapidly rises and i don't like this. I want to devide view methods from other model methods, what is the best practice for this?

Comment: model != activeRecord for table,you can multiple models for the same objects, and you can have it inherit the way you want, for example a common way i split "fat models" is by having module specific functions in models within that module only, these models inherit from the base active record.

Comment: @Manquer can you show some example in answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models are becoming large and unwieldy because you are following the  recommended way of *"Fat model and thin controller"* design. As you have noticed the models in any medium-sized project over time become obese very quickly!

#### First some theory

To solve this, first it has to be understood that **Models are NOT just classes or objects. Model is a layer.**

The fundamental logic behind the popularity and emergence of MVC as a design pattern is the philosophy of [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Fundamentally there are two layers in MVC: presentation and model layers.

Presentation layer breaks down further into controllers, views, widgets, templates, layouts  and so on.

Similarly model layer breaks into domain objects, storage abstractions and services.

Domain Objects is what we think of as "models" generally, and active record can be considered to be part of storage abstraction.

The **tl;dr version** is basically that there can be multiple model files which call the same activeRecord patterns

#### How to slim that model!

First separate the logical functions into different groups, for example if `User` model contains a set of functions for authentication, a set of functions for say analytic reporting on usage and another set of functions for calculating/formatting data for views (gridView, widgets, listView etc) and another set of functions that have core actions needed by all like `rules` and `relations` etc. Split them in  classes like this

```
class User extends CActiveRecord {
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
    // This slimmed used class contains only core functions like 
    // rules, relations, attributeLabels, and perhaps search usually functions generated by gii 
    // + anything you think will be needed by all the other models 
}
```

Your authentication class looks like this

```
class UserAuthentication extends User { 
     public static function model($className=__CLASS__) {
          return parent::model($className);
     }
     // All functions only related to authentication
}
```

Your UI/Formatting class looks like this

```
class UserUI extends User {
     public static function model($className=__CLASS__) {
           return parent::model($className);
     }
    // Only formatting and other view related functions
```

}

Your Analatics/report class looks like this

```
class UserReports extends User {
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__) {
          return parent::model($className);
     }
     // All functions that are used for reports 
}
```

Ideally you should split all these into separate modules, along with other models for example report module will contains all the report domain objects.

This makes programming in larger teams easier. Tests, UI,controllers, layouts pretty much everything can be written independently of each other, and each module can communicate to each other via services (the third model component)  like interfaces

Comment: Genuine question.. why would you prefer this approach over the use of behaviors? Behaviors are more flexible, as a model can have more than one, and can extend a root behavior (such as Analytics) to reduce common reporting code between different models.

Comment: many reasons not to do that, most important is that any attached behavior cannot override any class methods of the component it is being attached to, which limits flexibility actually

Comment: Indeed.. but it can override a method in a base behavior, and it can make use of the events such as afterSave/afterDelete. 
Plus I'd argue that you are much more likely to want to override a general Analytic function (continuing my example) than a component method.
Furthermore it wouldn't be too difficult to extend CActiveRecord to use a behavior method over an owner method, effectively allowing overrides.

Comment: Perhaps you could give some of the other reasons too.. again genuinely interested as we have similar problems in our projects.

Comment: @arth hmm.. if you are coding in a pure OO language like say ruby,or event driven language like JS you can even start with an empty object and build all methods dynamically, but in PHP while support is there, it is not generally used so extensively. AFAIK you cannot extend activeRecord or any other PHP class like the way you have described, the limitation is in the language not framework.

Comment: With regards to other reasons most of it is opinionated, performance is my reason i personally don't have data but events generally seem to take more time see http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/42954-performance-impact-of-behaviors/page__view__findpost__p__204066,

Answer (score 0):

You should have to create a getVar() and setVar() methods for each attributes, unless you are overriding the value.

For example. This is ok :-

```
public function getName()
{
    return 'My name is '.$this->name;
}
```

whereas this is not necessary, as it is automatically generated.

```
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

Therefore, you can say

```
echo $model->name;
// or
echo $model->getName();

$model->name = 'Tom';
// or
$model setName('Tom')
```

without creating getter and setter methods in the model.

References:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/